# Why does JavaScript write an element to the console but not update the css display value via a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completing an assignment for university as part of a group. We have encountered an issue with a certain event not triggering when using JavaScript to change css properties on button click. We are not looking for anyone to write/re-write our code to be industry standard, but we are looking to work out (with a little help from you) where we have gone wrong.

We are tasked with writing a report and presenting it in webpage format. 
We are writing the page using HTML/CSS and a small amount of JavaScript for things like drop-down menus and displaying sections of the page on button click.

The particular issue we can't work out (code below) is when a menu button is clicked, the JS should populate the heading of the page and display a `div` in the body.

I can either get it to work as intended, though only 3 `div` are referenced (the code seems to ignore the array elements after the 3rd), or get it to work with all headings but no `div` are referenced (per below).

CMVE as follows (full code below):

```js
let sections = ["Cooper", "Jenna", "Lyly", "Mick", "Samuel", "Stanton", "Welcome"];
var visSection = null;

/* var i;
 for (i=0; i<sections.length;i++) {
  console.log(sections[i]);
 }
*/
function changeActiveSection(sectionID) {
  if (visSection === sectionID) {
    visSection = null;
  } else {
    visSection = sectionID;
  }
  hideSections();
}

function hideSections() {
  var i, targetSection, headerText;
  for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    targetSection = sections[i];
    section = document.getElementById(visSection);
    if (visSection === targetSection) {
      //    console.log(visSection, targetSection, section);
      section.style.display = "block";
      headerText = visSection;
    } else {
      section.style.display = "none";
    }
    populateHeader(headerText);
  }
}

function populateHeader(headerText) {
  var ob;
  ob = document.getElementById("header-content");
  ob.innerText = headerText;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="header-content" style="display: block;">Welcome to The A2-Group-12 Team</h1>
  </header>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Stanton')">Stanton</a>
  <div id="Stanton" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
    <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
    <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
    <p> Stanton </p>
  </div>
  <script>
  //Insert JS from JS snippet
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I feel we may be misunderstanding a datatype somewhere perhaps, but we are all still learning and have been staring at this for days (the issue is probably right in front of our eyes!).

---

Full code Snippet with CSS:

```js
let sections = ["Cooper", "Jenna", "Lyly", "Mick", "Samuel", "Stanton", "Welcome"];
var visSection = null;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  console.log(sections[i]);
}

function changeActiveSection(sectionID) {
  if (visSection === sectionID) {
    visSection = null;
  } else {
    visSection = sectionID;
  }
  hideSections(visSection);
}

function hideSections(sectionID2) {
  var i, targetSection, headerText;
  for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    targetSection = sections[i];
    section = document.getElementById(sectionID2);
    if (visSection === targetSection) {
      console.log(visSection, targetSection, section);
      section.style.display = "block";
      headerText = visSection;
    } else {
      section.style.display = "none";
    }
    populateHeader(headerText);
  }
}

function populateHeader(headerText) {
  var ob;
  ob = document.getElementById("header-content");
  ob.innerText = headerText;
}

var dropdown = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var i, objCol;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/*Sets the font family for entire page.
removes entire margin for body section to create borderless display.*/

body {
  font-family: Arial, Veranda, Serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Sets attributes for the nav menu root element*/

#nav-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #353940;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}


/*specifies hyperlink button text attributes*/

#nav-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/*Specifies most dropdown button attributes.*/

button.drop-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #353940;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/*Active class to highlight activated dropdown buttons*/

button.active {
  background: #230fa8;
}


/*container class for dropdown menu items - hidden by default (display is manupulated via JS)*/

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #4a5059;
}


/*specifies layout for dropdown menu items*/

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


/*keeps header in line with rest of body*/

#header-content {
  padding-left: 17%;
}


/*specifies positioning for body container divs*/

.body-panel {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 17%;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment 2 Group 12</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="header-content" style="display: block;">Welcome to The A2-Group-12 Team</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <nav id="nav-menu">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Welcome')">Home</a>
      <button class="drop-button">About Us &#x25BC </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Stanton')">Stanton</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Jenna')">Jenna</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Cooper')">Cooper</a>
      </div>
      <button class="drop-button">Profile &#x25BC;</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('IT Work')">IT Work</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Industry Data')">Industry Data</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Our Project')">Our Project</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('IT Technologies')">IT Technologies</a>

    </nav>
    <div id="Welcome" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> </h2>
      <p> Please select an option from the menu. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Stanton" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Stanton </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Jenna" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Jenna </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Cooper" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Cooper </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script>
    //JS from snippet goes here
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `populateHeader(headerText);` shouldn't be part of the loop

Comment: Can you create a codepen or something we can run the code on?

Comment: @Chillin' that would be using the code snippet thingy (technical term) yeah?

Comment: @SamuelEverson Yea :) I did actually copy and paste your code in to a html file but the css doesnt exist so Im seeing a crappy version of it. and its hard to see what its suppose to do properly

Comment: Also just so I'm following you right, can you create a list of the steps I can produce to accurately see the problem. Some questions Im wondering, 1) Does it matter which menu item i click?  2) If I copy the second section of code, is that the one that produces the half-working version, or is that the first bit?

Comment: It will work when you use `Welcome` as id ;)

Comment: `section` will always be the div with the given id (`Stanton` in this case). The problem is that you change it's visibility in both ways (`block` <-> `none`) in every round of the loop. So for `Stanton` its: none, none, none, none, none, show, none

Comment: @chillin' the CMVE is just condensed 'full code' so the code here is specific to the title. I thought the other issue was worth mentioning but it occurs when values are parsed (?) via methiods in the function. I can post a separate question about that though if need be. As for which menu item, no, they should all (currently) display the placeholder data in the div (which will be unique to each div later on). So when the link is clicked, it should populate the header title with the name, and the div with the ID of the same name by changing the div display style to block. It's not triggering tho

Comment: @Chillin' also edited full code to run as snipped and added missing css. sorry for that!

Comment: @Andreas I think I'm following along what you're saying... Testing now with the for loop structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let sections = ["Cooper", "Jenna", "Lyly", "Mick", "Samuel", "Stanton", "Welcome"];
var visSection = null;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  console.log(sections[i]);
}

function changeActiveSection(sectionID) {
  if (visSection === sectionID) {
    visSection = null;
  } else {
    visSection = sectionID;
  }
  hideSections(visSection);
}

function hideSections(sectionID2) {
  var i, targetSection, headerText;
  for(i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            targetSection = sections[i];
            section = document.getElementById(targetSection);
            if(visSection === targetSection) {
            console.log(visSection, targetSection, section);
              section.style.display = "block";
              populateHeader(visSection); // moved to here as per Andreas point
            } else {
              
              if (typeof(section) != 'undefined' && section != null){
                    section.style.display = "none";
                 }
              
            }
            //populateHeader(headerText); <- move as per Andreas point
        }   
    }

function populateHeader(headerText) {
  var ob;
  ob = document.getElementById("header-content");
  ob.innerText = headerText;
}

var dropdown = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var i, objCol;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/*Sets the font family for entire page.
removes entire margin for body section to create borderless display.*/

body {
  font-family: Arial, Veranda, Serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Sets attributes for the nav menu root element*/

#nav-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #353940;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}


/*specifies hyperlink button text attributes*/

#nav-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/*Specifies most dropdown button attributes.*/

button.drop-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #353940;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: visible;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/*Active class to highlight activated dropdown buttons*/

button.active {
  background: #230fa8;
}


/*container class for dropdown menu items - hidden by default (display is manupulated via JS)*/

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #4a5059;
}


/*specifies layout for dropdown menu items*/

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


/*keeps header in line with rest of body*/

#header-content {
  padding-left: 17%;
}


/*specifies positioning for body container divs*/

.body-panel {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 17%;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment 2 Group 12</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="header-content" style="display: block;">Welcome to The A2-Group-12 Team</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <nav id="nav-menu">
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Welcome')">Home</a>
      <button class="drop-button">About Us &#x25BC </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Stanton')">Stanton</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Jenna')">Jenna</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Cooper')">Cooper</a>
      </div>
      <button class="drop-button">Profile &#x25BC;</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('IT Work')">IT Work</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Industry Data')">Industry Data</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('Our Project')">Our Project</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeActiveSection('IT Technologies')">IT Technologies</a>

    </nav>
    <div id="Welcome" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> </h2>
      <p> Please select an option from the menu. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Stanton" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Stanton </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Jenna" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Jenna </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Cooper" class="body-panel" style="display: none;">
      <h2> this is a placeholder heading </h2>
      <p> this is some placeholder body text. </p>
      <p> Cooper </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script>
    //JS from snippet goes here
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Graham, works as intended! I had established from @Andreas comments in the question there was something iffy with the for loop and got to the point that the else statement was not working as intended. I see you've added some extra bits to take into account when there is nothing there and will study it further - thanks again so much for the time and effort!

Comment: Thought I better add in comments that the first answer given (below) by me was kept due to conversation being interesting enough to explain problems with the code. Example above is a correction of the code that works (BUT dont use it as an example of how to do things properly, it is only for learning about errors in given question).

Comment: No problem, hope it helps you write a much better version now you see the problem (hint, passing the item in as a variable is the correct way to do it and turn 2 functions into 1)

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is not my strong point but we're only at the beginning of the degree so this has been a great learning curve!

Comment: Good luck in your Degree, stuff like this is the best way to learn, as i said try and improve the function so it doesn't rely on Global Variables and that will really help you improve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `for` loop.

You are passing in the `sectionID2` so it is always the item selected and stored as `section`.

You loop sets the visibility of the item for every iteration instead of the current section that is being tested against.

change `section = document.getElementById(sectionID2);` to `section = document.getElementById(targetSection);` and it should work (untested).

```
for(i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
                targetSection = sections[i];
                section = document.getElementById(targetSection);
                if(visSection === targetSection) {
                console.log(visSection, targetSection, section);
                  section.style.display = "block";
                  populateHeader(visSection); // moved to here as per Andreas point
                } else {
                  section.style.display = "none";
                }
                //populateHeader(headerText); <- move as per Andreas point
            }
```

Comment: `headerText` will only change once hence `populateHeader()` shouldn't be called on every round of the loop.

Comment: headerText will work fine, I think you commented before I corrected properly. `section` changes within the loop.

Comment: It will be correct, but still it will produce `sections.length - 1` unnecessary `populateHeader()` calls because `headerText` will only be changed once. It's not related to the problem of TO, just a code smell ;)

Comment: i see what you mean, I wasn't focusing on that I was just correcting why his sections didn't show at all, you are correct I misunderstood you.

Comment: I've also found when making the above mentioned change I get the good ol' `Cannot read property 'style' of null` in the console and nether the div appears nor the heading populates.

Comment: Did say untested :-P Your problem now lies in the fact that some items in your `sections` array do not exist in the DOM so I will leave you to work out how to check for that. `section.style.display = "none"` <- this bit

Comment: while debugging, its because the sectionID2 doesnt exist... it comes back as null

Comment: sectionID2 is irrelevant in the code now - section is defined within the loop on each iteration - his array of sections do not match elements within the DOM

Comment: @Chillin' oh no, the perils of horrible coding practices. I'd intended to remove the sectionID2 method altogether (as I didn't actually see the point of parsing the string that existed otherwise). The MCVE produces the same problem without any ref to sectionID2.

Comment: I just added a fiddle that works....was better than removing a good conversation. You are right Samuel, working around issues caused by bad practices causes lots of headaches, but you can work on that later, we all have to learn and bad code is part of the process sadly :-). See if fiddle below helps you understand how everything works (throw some more `console.logs` in there) and also understand why you were getting the error (and how I corrected for it).